# Holo-themed App falls back to default Android theme

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

my problem is an Android app, that uses `android:Theme` as a default style and `android:Theme.Holo.Light` for OSes of version 11 and newer and `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` for v14 and newer.

The app project was created using the ADT Eclipse-wizzard, so the `AndroidManifest.xml` sets `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`, and there are three `styles.xml` files, one in the `values`, `values-v11`, and `values-v14` folders respectively. The default `styles.xml` sets

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```

the `styles.xml` in `values-v11` sets

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

and finally `styles.xml` in `values-v14` sets

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This worked nicely for quite some time. I've checked the appearance for gingerbread using an emulator and the Holo-theme on a Galaxy SIII.

But now, also the Samsung phone will only use the classic android:Theme, no matter what I set in the `style.xml`s. I've also tried to raise the `minSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to 16 and to set the Holo-theme in the default `styles.xml`. Cleaning up and rebuilding had no effect either.

The Holo-theme is happily ignored by the app, and I don't know where else I can try looking to fix things.

Any help or pointers are very much appreciated.

**Update**

If I replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` with

```
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

everything works fine (`AppBaseTheme` is the platform-dependent parent theme for the customized platform-independent `AppTheme`). It somehow looks as if the Android runtime is lazy and does not care to look for the the most specific version of `AppBaseTheme`, but always takes the one found in `values/styles.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after several unsuccessful cleans I took a different approach and tried to rename `AppTheme` to `MyTheme` (and updating the reference in `AndroidManafest.xml` accordingly). Now the app references the correct AppBaseTheme for each version of Android.